# ¿Cómo imprimir una jerarquía de operaciones de manera estética?

Tags: python, math

Entiendo de sobra que python por sí mismo puede evaluar los operadores aritméticos y que es contraproducente y suena ilógico mostrar el proceso "jerárquico" para llegar al resultado. Pero, como estoy desarrollando ejercicios para mis alumnos, me sería muy sencillo hacerlo de esta manera.

Bien, aclarado el punto anterior, quiero comenzar diciendo que he buscado en diferentes sitios sobre la jerarquía de operaciones "de manera estética" en python, y no he encontrado absolutamente nada como lo que estoy planteando.

Primeramente se me ocurrió crear esto definiendo los "operadores estéticos" en listas:

```
operadores=['÷', '√', '^', '×', '+', '-']
operadores_sin_suma=['√', '-', '']
Parentesis=['(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '']
```

El segundo punto fue crear una variable llamada `numero_aleatorio`, que define la cantidad de veces que itera el ciclo **for**, después hice el ciclo **for** para iterar una cantidad de veces lo que la variable aleatoria "decida". Posteriormente creé dos variables `x` y `y` cuya función es elegir dos números aleatorios que serán evaluados por los operadores. Por consiguiente, mediante una condicional determiné si `x` y `y` no se encontraban en una lista donde almacena las jerarquías de operaciones, llamado `almacenado`, pues se agregan:

```
almacenado=[]
numero_aleatorio=randint(2,10)
for i in range(numero_aleatorio):
    x,y=randint(1,30), randint(1,30)
    if x and y not in almacenado:
        
        elegir_operador,elegir_otro=choice(operadores), choice(operadores_sin_suma)
```

Y finalmente, pues se imprime:

```
operaciones=(f'{elegir_otro}{x} {elegir_operador} {y}')
almacenado.append(operaciones)
```

En otro post (que Abufalia comentó) había leído sobre cómo imprimir estéticamente las potencias:

```
def unicode_exp(exp):
    if exp == 1:
       return chr(0xB9)
    if exp == 2 or exp == 3:
       return chr(0xB0 + exp)
    else:
       return chr(0x2070 + exp)
```

Y claro, lo implementé en otros problemas. Pero en este caso va lo siguiente:
¿cómo puedo imprimir la jerarquía de operaciones con los `Parentesis`, `operadores` y que sea evaluado? Que se vea estéticamente algo así: **{8+[2-(2+4(3² x 4) - 60) + 16  ÷ 4 + √100]+5}**

Me sería de gran utilidad si se pudiera imprimir aunque sea la jerarquía estética. De antemano muchas gracias y saludos!

Comment: Por ejemplo quieres imprimir `(2*3)+6`??

Comment: Sería más fácil entender si pones ejemplos. No queda muy claro eso de "estético". ¿Quieres decir "agradable a la vista"?

Comment: No va directamente a la respuesta, pero tal vez sea de ayuda... Si eres un profesor de matemáticas y quieres hacer demostraciones interactivas que sean muy agradables podrías utilizar algo como [Processing](https://processing.org/).

Comment: @CandidMoe Quiero hacer "agradable a la vista" por ejemplo esto:  **-(2+4(3² x 4) - 60) + 16  ÷ 4 + √100** Ojo, acabo de añadirlo a la pregunta.

Comment: @Christian Exactamente quiero imprimir algo como eso

Comment: @FranAcuna Lo voy a revisar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar una jerarquía de operaciones podemos utilizar expresiones regulares definidas.

```
'({}*{})÷{}' : '({}*{})/{}'
```

En este caso, python puede evaluar el orden jerarquico de dicha operación, siempre y cuando se especifique qué orden quieres que python siga, utilizando los paréntesis.

Posteriormente, con un rango numérico definido aleatorio, en una comprensión de listas, podemos determinar los valores que pueden tomar las expresiones regulares:

```
a,b,c  = [randint(0, 30) for _ in range(3)]
```

Lo anterior es para evitar redundancia y ahorrar espacio, evitando lo siguiente:

```
a,b,c = randint(0, 30), randint(0, 30), randint(0, 30)
```

Esta es una manera poco óptima de realizarlo, por lo que se recomienda una comprensión de listas.

Ahora falta mediante dos variables, determinar la parte estética y la parte matemática a evaluar, esas mismas variables tomarán la expresión regular que será elegida aleatoriamente mediante `choice`, las diferentes expresiones regulares que existan en el diccionario de `fmts`:

```
#Se toma la expresión regular de forma aleatoria que se encuentre en fmts
view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))

#expr toma los valores numéricos a evaluar 
expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)

#Mientras que view_expr toma los valores estéticos para mostrar
view_expr = view_expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)
```

Finalmente, mediante una variable, evaluamos la expresión regular que ha tomado la variable `expr`:

```
dato = eval(expr)
```

Si quieres añadir filtros para evitar errores, podemos añadir excepciones para evitar que el código se detenga en una determinada iteración y podemos añadir condicionales para evitar divisiones entre cero, o resultados muy grandes.
El código completo quedaría así:

```
from random import randint, choice

for i in range(10000):
  fmts = {

    'C[({}-{})*{}]/{}U+({}-{})*({}+{})' : '((({}-{})*{})/{})+({}-{})*({}+{})'

    }

  a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z  = [randint(0, 30) for _ in range(8)]

  view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
  expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)
  view_expr = view_expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)
       
  try:
    

    dato = eval(expr)
    if '.0' in str(dato):
      if -150 <= dato <= 100:
        print(view_expr.replace('C','{').replace('U','}'))
        print(int(dato))
        print('\n')
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(view_expr.replace('C','{').replace('U','}'))
    print('No tiene solución porque no se puede dividir entre 0') 
    print('\n')
```